# Initialization lists in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization-list

I've heard that the advantage of using initialization lists in constructor would be that there will be no extra copies of class type objects. But what does it mean for the following code in class T constructor? If i comment the assignment and use initialization lists what would be the difference?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ostream;

class X {

public:

    X(float f_x = 0, float f_y = 0):x(f_x), y(f_y) {}


    ~X() {}

    X(const X& obj):x(obj.x), y(obj.y) {}

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, X &obj);

private:
    float x;
    float y;
};

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, X &obj)
{ os << "x = " << obj.x << " y = " << obj.y; return os;}

class T {

public:

    T(X &obj) : x(obj) { /* x = obj */ }

    ~T() { }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &os, T &obj);

private:

    X x;

};

ostream& operator << (ostream &os, T &obj)
{ os << obj.x; return os; }

int main()
{
    X temp_x(4.6f, 6.5f);

    T t(temp_x);

    cout << t << endl;

}
```

Comment: Not sure if relevant to your question, but you'd probably want T( X const& obj ).

Comment: @K-ballo: Yes i forgot that, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's exactly what you already said.  If you don't use the initializer list, then the default constructor will get called first, and then the assignment operator will get called.

In your example, this is relatively benign (the compiler may even optimise this, I think).  But in other cases, it's simply not possible to avoid the initializer list.  Imagine if `X` didn't have a public assignment operator.

Comment: Ah, I was missing the overloaded assignment operator function to notice that effect in my code. I confused it with copy constructor!

Answer (score 5):

If you use **Assignment**, then:
`x` will be default constructed first &
then assigned with `obj`.

The cost is, **Default Construction + Assignment**

---

If you use **Member initializer list** then:
`x` will be constructed and initialized with `obj`.

The cost is, **Construction** only

Answer (score 2):

```
T(X &obj) : x(obj) {}
```

will copy construct x from obj, while

```
T(X &obj){ x = obj; }
```

will construct a default x, only to then replace it with the values from obj.

If you intent to construct a member object, you should do it in the initialization list.